# Eliminar consonantes de una cadena java

Tags: java

Quiero eliminar las consonantes de una cadena, es decir si se introduce **hola**, que su salida imprima **oa**. Tengo este código, pero no me lo hace

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class vocales {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Escriba una cadena para separar vocales.");
    String x = teclado.next();
    int s = x.length();
    char k;
        for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
            k = x.charAt(i);
            if ((k != 'a') || (k != 'e') || (k != 'i') || (k != 'o')
                    || (k != 'u')) {
                k = ' ';
            }
            System.out.print(k);
        }
    }
}
```

¿Alguien ve el fallo? Para separar las consonantes de las vocales, es decir de hola hl, si que me lo hace bien pero para la otra forma no.

Comment: El primer fallo es que no estas sustituyendo nada. k es una variable distinta a x.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Las cadenas en Java son **immutables**. Esto significa que no puedes modificar su contenido de ninguna manera.

Lo que puedes hacer es crear una nueva cadena que no posea las consonantes. Esto lo logras tras recorrer todos los caracteres de tu cadena original y, caracter por caracter, ir agregando los caracteres que correspondan.

```
String x = teclado.next();
String sinConsonantes = "";
int s = x.length();
char k;
for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
    k = x.charAt(i);
    if (!esConsonante(k)) {
        sinConsonantes += k;
    }
}
System.out.println("Cadena original: " + x);
System.out.println("Cadena sin consonantes: " + sinConsonantes);

//...

public static boolean esConsonante(char c) {
    //char se puede tratar como un entero
    //asociándolo al código UTF-8 apropiado
    //lo bueno es que los primeros 128 valores de UTF-8
    //se asocian a los valores de código ASCII
    //donde los valores entre 65 y 90 corresponden a
    //las letras A B C hasta la Z (mayúsculas)
    //y los valores 97 al 122 corresponden a las letras
    //a b c hasta la z (minúsculas)
    //como estamos en español, también debemos considerar
    //el caso de la Ñ y ñ (165 y 164, respectivamente)

    //primero evaluemos las mayúsculas
    //c >= 65 & c <= 90 significa que es una letra mayúscula
    //c != 'A' que sea diferente de la letra A
    //lo mismo para las otras vocales en mayúscula
    //se agrega un OR en caso que el caracter sea la Ñ (165)

    //luego evaluamos las minúsculas
    //similar al caso anterior
    //los pongo por separado para facilitar la lectura y comprensión
    //de lo que está sucediendo
    boolean result = false;
    if ((c >= 65 && c=< 90 && c != 'A' && c != 'E'
        && c != 'I' && c != 'O' && c != 'U') || c == 165) {
        result = true;
    } else if ((c >= 97 && c=< 122 && c != 'a' && c != 'e'
        && c != 'i' && c != 'o' && c != 'u') || c == 164) {
        result = true;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Modificando un poco tu codigo, cambie las condiciónes `k != 'a'` por una condición en código ascii `k != 97`y asi sucesivamente revisa este link http://ascii.cl/es/, y en ves de la desigualdad use la igualdad, te dejo el código:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class vocales {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    String x = "como esta usted amiga";
    int s = x.length();
    char k=' ';

        for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
            k = x.charAt(i);

            if ((k == 97) || (k == 111) || (k==101) || (k==105) || (k==117)) {

                  System.out.println(k);
            }else{
                  k = ' ';
                  System.out.println(k);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

> entrada de ejemplo ="como esta usted amiga"
>
> salida :  o o e a u e a i a

haciendolo para consontantes, vocales, dejo un ejemplo

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class vocales {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    String x = "como esta usted amiga";
    String cadenaSoloConsonantes="";
    String cadenaSoloVocales="";
    int s = x.length();
    char k=' ';

        for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
            k = x.charAt(i);

            if ((k == 97) || (k == 111) || (k==101) || (k==105) || (k==117)) {


                  cadenaSoloVocales+=k;
            }else{
                  cadenaSoloConsonantes+=k;

            }

        }
   System.out.println("cadena: "+x);
   System.out.println("cadena solo vocales: "+cadenaSoloVocales);
   System.out.println("cadena solo consonantes: "+cadenaSoloConsonantes);
    }
}
```

Comment: Cuidado. Esto no funciona si se ingresan símbolos.

Comment: lo que dice @LuiggiMendoza es cierto, asumi que son palabras solamente, sin simbolos.

Answer (score 1):

Por si a caso que no es parte de los requerimientos de solucionar la tarea sin expresiónes regulares, otra solución muy simple usandolos. Hay varios métodos utiles usando expresiones regulares - o `regex` - en la clase `String` y sirven para producir codigo corto y bien entendible, una vez que uno se acostumbro a `regex`.

Asumiendo que la meta es eliminar todos vocales **o** eliminar todos consonantes:

```
    // usando string.replaceAll(String regex, String remplazo)
    String fuente = "Hola, saquemos caracteres";
    System.out.println(fuente);
    // para mejor comparación el remplazo con un espacio
    System.out.println(fuente.replaceAll("[aeiouAEIOU]", " "));
    System.out.println(fuente.replaceAll("[^aeiouAEIOU\\s\\W_0-9]", " "));
    // y el resultado eliminando los caracteres
    System.out.println(fuente.replaceAll("[aeiouAEIOU]", ""));
    System.out.println(fuente.replaceAll("[^aeiouAEIOU\\s\\W_0-9]", ""));
```

que produce:

```
Hola, saquemos caracteres
H l , s q  m s c r ct r s
 o a   a ue o   a a  e e 
Hl, sqms crctrs
oa, aueo aaee
```

Comment: +1 buena solucion, de diferente manera pero util, aporta conocimiento

Comment: Cuidado. Considera que con `[^aeiouAEIOU\\s]` se pierden los símbolos.

Comment: Cierto, cuando escribí la regex tuve ejemplos sin símbolos en mente, luego usé uno con en los tests. lo voy a editar para tomarlos en cuenta.

Answer (score 1):

Y que tal usando un StringBuffer?

```
private static void repetidos(StringBuffer stb){
    //Elimina las vocales de un StringBuffer y lo muestra
    for(int i=0; i<stb.length(); i++){
        if(stb.charAt(i) == 'a' ||
                stb.charAt(i) == 'e' ||
                stb.charAt(i) == 'i' ||
                stb.charAt(i) == 'o' ||
                stb.charAt(i) == 'u' ||
                stb.charAt(i) == 'A' ||
                stb.charAt(i) == 'E' ||
                stb.charAt(i) == 'I' ||
                stb.charAt(i) == 'O' ||
                stb.charAt(i) == 'U'
                ){
            stb.deleteCharAt(i);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(stb);
}
```

Puede parecer que es un código farragoso para solo quitar unas vocales, pero el StringBuffer nos permite tener una cadena que puede ser modificable, con lo cual.
Además si necesitamos poner la cadena en el StringBuffer solo usamos una linea como esta:

```
stb.append(cadena);
```

Donde la cadena es un String. Lo que hace es parecido al

`cadena.replace([aeiou], "");`

Answer (score 0):

Eliminar Vocales de una Cadena.

ENTRADA "¡Este sitio web es para los mejores!";

IMPRESION "st st wb s pr ls mjrs"

```
String texto = "¡Este sitio web es para los mejores!";
  System.out.println(texto);
  System.out.println(texto.replaceAll("[aeiouAEIOU]"," "));
```